# How to make multiple (if statements) print in the same line?

Tags: if-statement

How to make multiple (if statements) print in the same line?

```
playingCard = input("Enter the card notation: ")

valid = False

if '2' in playingCard:
    print('Two')
    valid = True

if '3' in playingCard:
    print('Three')
    valid = True

if '4' in playingCard:
    print('Four')
    valid = True

if '5' in playingCard:
    print('Five')
    valid = True

if '6' in playingCard:
    print('Six')
    valid = True

if '7' in playingCard:
    print('Seven')
    valid = True

if '8' in playingCard:
    print('Eight')
    valid = True

if '9' in playingCard:
    print('Nine')
    valid = True

if '10' in playingCard:
    print('Ten')
    valid = True

if 'A' in playingCard or 'a' in playingCard:
    print("Ace")
    valid = True

if 'J' in playingCard or 'j' in playingCard:
    print('Jack')
    valid = True

if 'Q' in playingCard or 'q' in playingCard:
    print("Queen")
    valid = True

if 'K' in playingCard or 'k' in playingCard:
    print("King")
    valid = True

if 'H' in playingCard or 'h' in playingCard:
    print("of Hearts")
    valid = True

if 'D' in playingCard or 'd' in playingCard:
    print("of Diamonds")
    valid = True

if 'S' in playingCard or 's' in playingCard:
    print("of Spades")
    valid = True

if 'C' in playingCard or 'c' in playingCard:
    print("of Clubs")
    valid = True

if valid == False:
    print("Invalid Card Entered")
```

If I type (QS) for example, the program will print:

```
  Queen
  of Spades
```

(on two different line)

I want the program to print:

```
  Queen of Spades
```

(on the exact same line)

Or if there is any simpler solution, which I believe there is.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Create two strings: One for the rank, one for the color. Then when you have validated the input and set those strings, print them as a single line.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `end` parameter to be an empty string (`''`) instead of the default newline (`\n`):

```py
if '2' in playingCard:
    print('Two', end = '')
    valid = True
```

Just replicate this same pattern in the other blocks of code.

NB: You'll need to add either a space at the end of the card number, or at the start of the suit. Otherwise you'll get the result `Twoof spades`

Either:

```py
print('Two ', end = '')
```

Or:

```py
print(' of spades')
```

Comment: If I type (13) it prints (Three), but I want it to print (Three) only for number 3, and for 13 (Invalid card entered)

Comment: @HashemBaha that's a different question. Your initial question was about using `print()` multiple times, but printing on one line. You should ask a new question about validating your input.

Comment: And about string comparisons, I guess.